# Applicative implementation of Const Monoid

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids

```
instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m) where
    pure _ = Const mempty
    Const f <*> Const v = Const (f `mappend` v)
```

**I do not understand how can the definition of `<*>` type-check.**

On the left side `f` is constrained by the signature of `<*>` as in the definition of Applicative

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

After changing the names to the current situation:

```
    (<*>) :: c (m -> b) -> c m -> c b
```

=> `f :: m -> *`.

On the left side `f` is the [first] parameter of `mappend`.

From the definition of Monoid

```
class Monoid a where
        mempty  :: a
        -- ^ Identity of 'mappend'
        mappend :: a -> a -> a
```

After changing the names to the current situation:

```
        mappend :: m -> m -> m
```

=> `f :: m`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> After changing the names to the current situation:
>
> ```
> (<*>) :: c (m -> b) -> c m -> c b
> ```
>
> => `f :: m -> *`.

Not quite. After changing the names to the current situation:

```
(<*>) :: Const m (a -> b) -> Const m a -> Const m b
```

Since a value of type `Const x y` is the constructor `Const` applied to a value of type `x`, this means `f :: m` (and `v :: m`), and we know `Monoid m` from the instance context.

Answer (score 6):

```
(<*>) :: f         (a->b) -> f         a -> f         b
      ≡  (Const m) (a->b) -> (Const m) a -> (Const m) b
      ≡  Const m (a->b) -> Const m a -> Const m b
      ≅        m        ->       m   ->       m
```

which is the signature of `<>` (aka `mappend`).